# Retaining categorical dtype upon dataframe concatenation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with identical column names and dtypes, similar to the following:

```
A             object
B             category
C             category
```

The categories are not identical in each of the dataframes.

When normally concatinating, pandas outputs:

```
A             object
B             object
C             object
```

Which is the expected behaviour as per [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/categorical.html).

However, I wish to keep the categorisation and wish to union the categories, so I have tried the union_categoricals across the columns in the dataframe which are both categorical. `cdf` and `df` are my two dataframes.

```
for column in df:
    if df[column].dtype.name == "category" and cdf[column].dtype.name == "category":
        print (column)
        union_categoricals([cdf[column], df[column]], ignore_order=True)

cdf = pd.concat([cdf,df])
```

This is still not providing me with a categorical output.

Comment: what version of pandas are you using?  I'm not able to replicate this behavior.

Comment: 0.20.1 - union_categoricals is new in version 0.19.0.

Comment: I get a `ValueError: incompatible categories in categorical concat` but I'm still on 0.18.1

Comment: Yep - `union_categoricals` appears to overcome exactly that issue - see the [merged pull request](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/13361)

Comment: I dunno.  You could always coerce back to category as in `df['A'] = df['A'].astype('category')`

Comment: FYI, the documentation linked is outdated. It matters because the old documentation [first says merging different categories will lead to ValueError](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/categorical.html#merging) and then that [it just returns object dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/categorical.html#concatenation). The new documentation [keeps only the correct latter description](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/user_guide/categorical.html?highlight=categorical#merging-concatenation).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't think this is completely obvious from the documentation, but you could do something like the following.  Here's some sample data:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'x':pd.Categorical(['dog','cat'])})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'x':pd.Categorical(['cat','rat'])})
```

Use `union_categoricals` to get consistent categories accros dataframes.  Try `df.x.cat.codes` if you need to convince yourself that this works.

```
from pandas.api.types import union_categoricals

uc = union_categoricals([df1.x,df2.x])
df1.x = pd.Categorical( df1.x, categories=uc.categories )
df2.x = pd.Categorical( df2.x, categories=uc.categories )
```

Concatenate and verify the dtype is categorical.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])

df3.x.dtypes
category
```

As @C8H10N4O2 suggests, you could also just coerce from objects back to categoricals after concatenating.  Honestly, for smaller datasets I think that's the best way to do it just because it's simpler.  But for larger dataframes, using `union_categoricals` should be much more memory efficient.

Comment: Thanks for this - ended up doing a mixture of coercing and unioning across the frame.

Answer (score 13):

To complement JohnE's answer, here's a function that does the job by converting to union_categoricals all the category columns present on all input dataframes:

```
def concatenate(dfs):
    """Concatenate while preserving categorical columns.

    NB: We change the categories in-place for the input dataframes"""
    from pandas.api.types import union_categoricals
    import pandas as pd
    # Iterate on categorical columns common to all dfs
    for col in set.intersection(
        *[
            set(df.select_dtypes(include='category').columns)
            for df in dfs
        ]
    ):
        # Generate the union category across dfs for this column
        uc = union_categoricals([df[col] for df in dfs])
        # Change to union category for all dataframes
        for df in dfs:
            df[col] = pd.Categorical(df[col].values, categories=uc.categories)
    return pd.concat(dfs)
```

Note the categories are changed in place in the input list:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2],
                  'x':pd.Categorical(['dog','cat']),
                  'y': pd.Categorical(['banana', 'bread'])})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'x':pd.Categorical(['rat']),
                  'y': pd.Categorical(['apple'])})

concatenate([df1, df2]).dtypes
```

Comment: I just learned the hard way that `pd.Categorical( df[col], categories=uc.categories )` will leave the category codes of `df[col]` unchanged, but remap them to categories according to `uc.categories`, likely associating them incorrectly. To avoid this, replace `df[col]` with `np.asarray(df[col])`.

Comment: Could you provide an example in which this is problematic? It seems to work fine for the toy example above and for my dataset

Comment: Depending on the pandas version, one might need `include=['category']`

Comment: For anyone else coming across this @FalafelPita is correct and using the suggested code will not map the categoricals correctly. You don't need to use np.asarray though. You can do this: `df[col] = pd.Categorical(df[col].values, categories=uc.categories)`. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't think FalafelPita or @Decko are correct. Or at least not regarding the most recent version of Pandas. I've both tried to reproduce their observations without success and also have walked through the Pandas code. [Here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/3701a9b1bfc3ad3890c2fb1fe1974a4768f6d5f8/pandas/core/arrays/categorical.py#L364) is the relevant code that handles re-coding when changing categories on a categorical type.

Comment: @MarkRucker you are correct. I just retested and with Pandas 0.24.1 and using `df[col]` instead of `df[col].values` gives the wrong result. With Pandas 0.24.2 on onwards it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was convenient to add two features to Tom Bug/Decko's answer:

1. Combine any categorical column present in multiple dfs, not just those present in all dfs.
2. Allow for a pathList argument rather than the dfs themselves (for cleaner code)

I also added an option to preserve the original dataframes, as df[col] modifies the original df if it is not copied first. By default it is enabled, but for optimal memory use you'll want to set this to `False` if you never need the original dfs again. Hope it is of use to someone.

````py
def pandasConcatWithCategoricals(dfs=[], pathList=[], preserveOriginalDfs=True, **readParquetKwargs):
    ''' Concatenates a list of dataframes, preserving categorical columns. '''
    # Imports
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas.api.types import union_categoricals
    from collections import defaultdict

    # Technicalities
    assert (max(len(dfs), len(pathList)) > 0), 'pandasConcatWithCategoricals: either dfs or pathList should be non-empty'
    assert (min(len(dfs), len(pathList)) == 0), 'pandasConcatWithCategoricals: either dfs or pathList should be empty'

    # Load dataframes
    if pathList:
        dfs = [pd.read_parquet(path, **readParquetKwargs) for path in pathList]
    else:
        if preserveOriginalDfs:
            dfs = [df.copy() for df in dfs]

    # Locate categorical columns
    dfsPerCategoricalColumn = defaultdict(list)
    for df in dfs:
        for col in df.select_dtypes(include='category').columns:
            dfsPerCategoricalColumn[col].append(df)

    # Generate overarching categories
    for col, dfsWithCol in dfsPerCategoricalColumn.items():     # col, dfsWithCol = next(iter(dfsPerCategoricalColumn.items()))
        joinedCategories = union_categoricals([df[col] for df in dfsWithCol])
        for df in dfsWithCol:
            df[col] = pd.Categorical(df[col], categories=joinedCategories.categories)

    # Concatenate
    return pd.concat(dfs)

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['a', 'b', 'c']}).astype('category')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4, 5, 6], 'b': ['d', 'e', 'f']}).astype('category')
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [7, 8, 9]}).astype('category')

df_mine = pandasConcatWithCategoricals([df1, df2, df3])
assert df_mine.astype(str).equals(pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).astype(str))```
````

Answer (score 0):

JohnE's answer is helpful, but in pandas 0.19.2, `union_categoricals` can only be imported as follow:

`from pandas.types.concat import union_categoricals`

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I'm getting a deprecation warning if I try your import and importing from `pandas.api.types` still works fine for me in version 23.4 and is in the documentation for 24.1.  I'll admit to not knowing the history of `union_categoricals` so perhaps your assertion was true in the past but might not be any longer.

Answer (score 0):

## Update Oct. 2023:

```py
for col in df1.select_dtypes(include="category").columns.intersection(
    # intersection of columns that are categorical in both dataframes
    df2.select_dtypes(include="category").columns
):
    # union of the categories in both dataframes' columns
    all_cats = df1[col].cat.categories.union(df2[col].cat.categories)
    df1[col] = df1[col].cat.set_categories(all_cats)
    df2[col] = df2[col].cat.set_categories(all_cats)
```

Example, tried with pandas 2.1.2 in python 3.11.1:

```py
>>> df1=pd.DataFrame({'x':pd.Categorical(['dog','cat'])})
>>> df2=pd.DataFrame({'x':pd.Categorical(['cat','rat'])})
>>> df1.x.dtype
CategoricalDtype(categories=['cat', 'dog'], ordered=False, categories_dtype=object)
>>> df2.x.dtype
CategoricalDtype(categories=['cat', 'rat'], ordered=False, categories_dtype=object)
>>> for col in df1.select_dtypes(include="category").columns.intersection(
...     df2.select_dtypes(include="category").columns
... ):
...     all_cats = df1[col].cat.categories.union(df2[col].cat.categories)
...     df1[col] = df1[col].cat.set_categories(all_cats)
...     df2[col] = df2[col].cat.set_categories(all_cats)
...
>>> df1.x.dtype
CategoricalDtype(categories=['cat', 'dog', 'rat'], ordered=False, categories_dtype=object)
>>> df2.x.dtype
CategoricalDtype(categories=['cat', 'dog', 'rat'], ordered=False, categories_dtype=object)
>>> df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
>>> df3.x.dtype
CategoricalDtype(categories=['cat', 'dog', 'rat'], ordered=False, categories_dtype=object)
```

---

## Original answer

All other answers use [`union_categoricals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.union_categoricals.html) to get a combined list of both dataframes' categories. Since this already combines the series of both dataframes, which is then discarded in favor of the following `pd.concat`, these answers add significant overhead.

It's also possible to just create a union over the categories:

```py
for col in (
    # intersection of columns that are categorical in both dataframes
    df1.select_dtypes(include="category").columns
    & df2.select_dtypes(include="category").columns
):
    # union of the categories in both dataframes' columns
    all_cats = df1[col].cat.categories | df2[col].cat.categories
    df1[col] = df1[col].cat.set_categories(all_cats)
    df2[col] = df2[col].cat.set_categories(all_cats)
```

I've tested this with unordered categories only. `union_categoricals` also covers ordering, for which it might be better suited.

Using the example from [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45642223/3410474):

```py
>>> df1=pd.DataFrame({'x':pd.Categorical(['dog','cat'])})
... df1.x.dtype
CategoricalDtype(categories=['cat', 'dog'], ordered=False)

>>> df2=pd.DataFrame({'x':pd.Categorical(['cat','rat'])})
... df2.x.dtype
CategoricalDtype(categories=['cat', 'rat'], ordered=False)

>>> for col in (
...     # intersection of columns that are categorical in both dataframes
...     df1.select_dtypes(include="category").columns
...     & df2.select_dtypes(include="category").columns
... ):
...     # union of the categories in both dataframes' columns
...     all_cats = df1[col].cat.categories | df2[col].cat.categories
...     df1[col] = df1[col].cat.set_categories(all_cats)
...     df2[col] = df2[col].cat.set_categories(all_cats)

>>> df1.x.dtype
CategoricalDtype(categories=['cat', 'dog', 'rat'], ordered=False)

>>> df2.x.dtype
CategoricalDtype(categories=['cat', 'dog', 'rat'], ordered=False)

>>> df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
... df3.x.dtype
CategoricalDtype(categories=['cat', 'dog', 'rat'], ordered=False)
```

Comment: On pandas 2.1.1 this is giving me a bunch of errors. `(
    # intersection of columns that are categorical in both dataframes
    df1.select_dtypes(include="category").columns
    & df2.select_dtypes(include="category").columns
)` leads to `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'` and `df1[col] = df1[col].cat.set_categories(all_cats)` gives `ValueError: Categorical categories must be unique`

Comment: @Danferno for pandas 2.x you need to replace `&` by `.intersect()` and `|` by `.union()`. I updated my answer accordingly. Using `.intersect()` and `union()` feels a bit less pythonic but is probably more robust anyway.